# Initializing a class error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, initialization

I have some class with this set :

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :title, :description

   def initialize
     validates_format_of_many([:title, :description])
   end

  def validates_format_of_many(inputs)
    if (!inputs.nil?)
      inputs.each do |input|
        validates_format_of input => /^[.]/, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false
        puts YAML::dump('test1')
      end
    else
      puts YAML::dump('test2')
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that I get some error message `undefined method`include?' for nil:NilClass`
and in the stack

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:257:in `method_missing'
/var/www/gitorious/app/models/campaign.rb:13:in `validates_format_of_many'
/var/www/gitorious/app/models/campaign.rb:12:in `each'
/var/www/gitorious/app/models/campaign.rb:12:in `validates_format_of_many'
/var/www/gitorious/app/models/campaign.rb:7:in `initialize'
/var/www/gitorious/app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:28:in `new'
/var/www/gitorious/app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:28:in `new'
```

Comment: See my answer bellow, more complete, hope to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly if you overwrite initialize, you should call super, this will allow the super_class to perform its initialization tasks

```
def initialize
  validates_format_of_many([:title, :description])
  super
end
```

But it is recommended for AR to use callbacks. Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Example:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :title, :description

  after_initialize { validates_format_of_many([:title, :description]) }

  def validates_format_of_many(inputs)
    if (!inputs.nil?)
      inputs.each do |input|
        validates_format_of input => /^[.]/, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false
        puts YAML::dump('test1')
      end
    else
      puts YAML::dump('test2')
    end
  end
end
```

But be careful cause your validates_format_of_many will be called for `Campaign.new` when creating a new record, and also for `Campaign.find ...` when loading records from the database